# Python Polynomial addition using parser

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, polynomials

I have two polynomial functions .
P = 3x^2 + 2x + 7
Q = 5x^2 + 2x^2+x
How can i perform addition on these polynomials using parser in python language.?

Comment: Use a regex to capture the individual items in each polynomial. Then put those items together in the correct Python syntax for a polynomial (eg, `P = 3*x**2 + 2*x + 7`). Use sympy to perform the polynomial addition.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough presentation. I hope it's not too difficult to follow.

Start with one of your polynomials, and discard the blanks for easier string processing. Use the first regex to identify the 'name' of the polynomial (P) and each of its terms for further processing. Now use a second regex.sub to place a multiplication sign before the variable in the polynomial term, if necessary. Use ordinary string replacement to replace carets with '**'.

Turn the list into a string. I did put in an equals sign but at this point I realised that I really didn't need or want the name of the polynomial for the purposes of making a conversion to sympy.

Final step was to use sympify to introduce the polynomial to sympy, and to give it a name, P. Adding polynomials in sympy is straightforward.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'P = 3x^2 + 2x + 7'.replace(' ', '')
>>> poly = []
>>> for term in regex.findall(r'[+-]?\d*\w+\^?\d*', s):
...     term = regex.sub(r'(\d*)([A-Za-z]\w*)(.*)', r'\1*\2\3', term)
...     term = term.replace('^', '**')
...     poly.append(term)
... 
>>> poly
['*P', '3*x**2', '+2*x', '+7']
>>> poly[0]=poly[0][1:]+'='
>>> poly = ''.join(poly)
>>> poly
'P=3*x**2+2*x+7'
>>> from sympy import *
>>> P =sympify(poly[2:])
>>> P
3*x**2 + 2*x + 7
```